# If $f(x) = cf(cx)$, show that $f(x)$ is inversely proportional to $x$

Tags: real-analysis

For $f:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$, if $f(x) = cf(cx)$, $\forall c\in \mathbb{R} \setminus \left\{{0}\right\}$, then prove that $f(x)$ is inversely proportional to $x$.

Comment: for $x\neq 0$ choose $c=\frac{1}{x}$, $x=0$ can be easily dealt with.

Comment: f (x) = f (1x) = xf (1x)/x =f (1)/x for x not 0.

Comment: The exception of course is f (0) = 0, seems to be defined and acceptable (f (0) = cf (0c) for all c so f (0)=0) and the only point where f(x) is not inversely proportional to x.  And it's the one point of discontinuity.  So that's a nitpick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that for any $x,y \neq 0$ such that $f(y) \neq 0$, we have
$$
\frac{f(x)}{f(y)} = \frac{\frac{y}{x}f(x \frac yx)}{f(y)} = \frac yx \frac{f(y)}{f(y)} = \frac{y}{x}
$$
We may thereby conclude (by any reasonable definition) that $f(x)$ is inversely proportional to $x$.

Comment: I'd nitpick and say that the function is defined for x=0 (0 is in the domain), that f (0)=0 and that the function is *not* inversely proportional.  But that is a nitpick.